# How do MySQL 5.7 virtual columns differ from views?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, virtual-columns

Starting reading point: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/29/generated-virtual-columns-in-mysql-5-7-labs/

Running some tests with the most recent percona 5.7  they seem to work well. Explain plans and wall time look pretty good but I'm not seeing any difference in show table status index_length or data_length.

How do you find the true footprint or overhead for using these?

Unlike views they do seem to be faster than bookmarked selects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views and virtual columns are similar, in that neither are materialized.  i.e. neither store any data or indexes, hence why your `index_length`+`data_length` remain the same.

Where they differ is:

1. Virtual columns are created on base tables, and will co-exist with columns which will be material.  This can be useful as it has more of a mixing/matching behavior than views.
2. Virtual columns permit indexes (which are materialized).  Views do not.

As a side note, another commonly used feature with some overlap here is triggers.  It is often better to have a virtual column than a trigger updating legacy columns on insert/update.

In response to this specific question:

> How do you find the true footprint or overhead for using these?

There is no footprint, and you will likely not see overhead.  Sure, there are hypothetical cases: If you have many virtual columns and `SELECT *` from a client then more data will be sent across the network (since rows are sent in full; clients don't know they can reconstruct certain data from virtual column definitions).

Comment: I don't get how in my test (using a json_extract virtual column, which was then indexed) didn't add any index_length on a 250M row test table though.  If it's ETL on the fly for columns fine but I can't buy magic indexes that perform w/o any noticeable footprint.

Comment: You are correct: indexes on virtual columns are *not* virtual, they exist as all other indexes do.  The reason you are not seeing the `Index_length` increase is because `innodb_stats_on_metadata` is disabled by default (so the value is cached).  Run `ANALYZE TABLE` and it will change :)